# Find repeated numbers sequence with regex

Tags: regex

I want to remove from a phone number list, repeated numbers like:

> 0000000000 1111111111 2222222222 ...

But ignoring matching groups:

> 1234512345 1212121212

Each phone number have 10 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
(\d)(\1){9}
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/tbTn46VE7g)

Comment: thanks! Much better than `(0{10}|1{10}|2{10}|3{10}|4{10}|5{10}|6{10}|7{10}|8{10}|9{10})`