# Regex to find exactly 11 repeating numbers

Tags: java, regex

My Regex:

```
^(\d)\1{2}.\1{3}.\1{3}-\1{2}$
```

Repetitions that aren't allowed:

```
000.000.000-00
111.111.111-11
222.222.222-22
333.333.333-33
444.444.444-44
555.555.555-55
666.666.666-66
888.888.888-88
999.999.999-99
```

It's working fine according to https://www.regex101.com/

So I'm trying to put it in Java, I already tried this way: `^(\\d)\\1{2}.\\1{3}.\\1{3}-\\1{2}$`, but definitely don't want to work.

My code:

```
if (hasTheSameDigits(cpfReplaced)) {
    msg = "All the digits of informed CPF are equal.";
}

public boolean hasTheSameDigits(String cpf) {
     return cpf.matches("^(\\d)\\1{2}\\1{3}\\1{3}\\1{2}$");
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: regex101 doesn't support the Java flavor of regular expressions. Better test with [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Comment: Also note that your regex would also match `111A111B111-11`.

Comment: *"I already tried this way: ^(\\d)\\1{2}.\\1{3}.\\1{3}-\\1{2}$, but definitely don't want to work."* can you post your code? I don't see reason why this would not work if used properly.

Comment: In that site you said, it gives me the regex that I said "^(\\d)\\1{2}.\\1{3}.\\1{3}-\\1{2}$".

Yes, it's a problem, but it will never happen, because that field has a mask that only accept digits

Comment: @developer033 I'm confused: the listed repetitions shall be allowed or not?

Comment: @developer033 Supposed the listed repetitions shall be allowed - as I suspect - the regex works fine for me, but the fact that RealSkeptic mentioned. I'll post my code, maybe that helps.

Comment: @yasd I suspect that purpose of this regex is to find things which we should not allow. So OP code can look like `boolean isValidNumber(String number){ return !number.matches(regex);}`.

Comment: Guys, I managed to make it work, it was just a little mistake, I was removing the mask from the field in another method and I didn't notice that. It's working fine, btw anyone could tell me what can I do to matches only digits, not the letters like "111A111B111-11".

Comment: @yasd "*I'll post my code, maybe that helps*" please don't post answers that states "*I can't reproduce your problem/your code works for me*". That is not what Stack Overflow is for. We want to have solutions for question which are reproducible. If question doesn't provide enough informations then it doesn't belong to Stack Overflow since it can't help anyone in the future. More info: [Are “works for me” answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: @Pshemo I thought adding real code might help - but okay. @developer033 `Pattern.compile("^(\\d)\\1{2}\\.\\1{3}\\.\\1{3}-\\1{2}$")` contains the dot correction RealSkeptic mentioned and `pattern.matcher("000.000.000-00").matches()` brings true for all strings in your list.

Comment: @yasd Now that OP edited his question and added code which lets us see what went wrong feel free to post answer explaining mistakes which ware made (like lack of `.` support). Feel free to also include some optimizations like precompiling regex once and reusing it in method like you did in your comment: `pattern.matcher("000.000.000-00").matches()`.

Comment: Now that I think more about this regex, I found a better solution, since I'm already replacing the non-digits characters, I can just simply change my regex to: `"^(\\d)(\\1){10}$"` [See it](http://rubular.com/r/JVD4JEDkxe)

Comment: Let me guess: http://stackoverflow.com/a/123681/1393766 :)

Comment: @Pshemo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880153/find-repeated-numbers-sequence-with-regex?rq=1) :)

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work: `([0-9])\1\1\.\1\1\1\.\1\1\1-\1\1\1`.

(Note: it bloats to this Java String because of the escapes: `"([0-9])\\1\\1\\.\\1\\1\\1\\.\\1\\1\\1-\\1\\1\\1"`.)

Explanation:

`([0-9])` finds a digit.

`\1` finds the same digit. And again. And Again. AND AGAIN.

`\.` matches a `.`

`-` matches a `-`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already found an answer as you can see in comments.. `^(\\d)(\\1){10}$ `.